# How do I control the memory and CPU footprint of an ECS deployment when using CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline

TL;DR: How do I change the memory and CPU requirements (or specify any details of the ECS task definition) after a CodePipeline targeting ECS has been deployed?

I have created a CodePipeline which deploys an ECS container. To achieve this my build step generates a file called imagedefinitions.json:

```
[
  {
    "name": "idws",
    "imageUri": "xxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxx/idws-dev:latest"
  }
]
```

(xxx for privacy, but you get the idea).

However, this image definitions file does not support all the details which are found in an ECS task definition. It only allows specification of a container URI. Where is the task configuration coming from?

What I find to be particularly odd is that this pipeline didn't work at all until I manually created a task definition in ECS that had a container of the same name as appears in the image definitions file. This undocumented requirement makes me assume that CodePipeline somehow inherits the task definition details from the service, which is irritating but not impossible to work around EXCEPT: If you try and change the task definition, the next time the pipeline runs all the task definition details revert to the task definition as it was configured at the time the pipeline was created. None of this is explained by the instructions for CodePipeline or ECS.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same issue as you - even tried adding a step at the end of the build (before deploy) to push my task definition JSON as a new revision - but the ECS deploy reverts it back every time.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Codepipeline ECS deploy quite a bit with cross account ECS clusters as well. The difference from your setup being, I create the ECS cluster (and task definitions, services, ECR repos, ELB etc) before the code pipeline, either via Terraform or Cloudformation.

Once the cluster and task definition is present, codepipeline merely updates "image" url in the task definition, creates a new version and deploys new tasks using this definition.

Creating the cluster separately worked for me as I don't need to create cluster/service/load balancer/autoscaling policies/rules etc every time my pipeline runs. Here are the templates I used to create my [ECS cluster (& other things it needs)](https://github.com/abiydv/cloudformation/tree/master/ecs) and [code pipeline](https://github.com/abiydv/cloudformation/tree/master/codepipeline), if it helps!

Comment: It makes sense that it updates the image url, but that's not what I'm experiencing. It is actually reverting the task definition to a previous task definition specification.

Comment: That's weird. Would you be able to post your pipeline json and task definition? Maybe add it to the opening post.

Comment: @DiscoMike I'm experiencing the same issue: its using an old task definition, but updating the revision to the latest. I even deregister/inactivate them, but it still seems to pull from an old definition. I'll post an answer if I can develop a solid workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The AWS CodePipeline ECS Deploy action seems to be looking at the most recent Task Definition that's tied to the Service that's being deployed to. This is based on the following experiment:

- Task Definition TDv1

  - Memory 128mb
- Deploy via Code Pipeline

  - Creates Task Definition TDv2
  - Memory 128mb
- Manually Update Task Definition TDv3

  - Memory *256mb*
- Deploy via Code Pipeline

  - Creates Task Definition TDv4

    - Memory 128mb **HERE'S THE GOTCHA, IT'S COPYING FROM TDv2**
- Manually Update Task Definition TDv5

  - Memory *1024mb*
- **Update Service to use TDv5**
- Deploy via Code Pipeline

  - Creates Task Definition TDv6

    - Memory 1024mb **BINGO, COPIES FROM TDv6**

Answer (score 0):

In your CodePipeline process, try plugging in a stage to deploy a Cloudformation stack where your ECS Task is declared. So your pipeline will look like

Source -> Codebuild (build and push the docker image) -> Deploy Cloudformation -> Deploy ECS

Here's an incomplete template:

```
    - Name: Build
      Actions:
        - Name: Build
          ActionTypeId:
            Category: Build
            Owner: AWS
            Version: 1
            Provider: CodeBuild
          Configuration:
            ProjectName: !Ref CodeBuildProject
          InputArtifacts:
            - Name: App
          OutputArtifacts:
            - Name: BuildOutput
          RunOrder: 1

    - Name: DeployCFN
      Actions:
        - Name: Deploy
          ActionTypeId:
            Category: Deploy
            Owner: AWS
            Provider: CloudFormation
            Version: '1'
          Configuration:
            ActionMode: CREATE_UPDATE
            Capabilities: CAPABILITY_IAM
            RoleArn: !GetAtt CloudformationRole.Arn
            StackName: 'ecs-task'
            TemplatePath: SourceOutput::ecs_template.yml
            ParameterOverrides: !Sub '{"Cpu": 512, "Memory: "2GB"}'
          InputArtifacts:
            - Name: SourceOutput
          RunOrder: 1

    - Name: DeployECS
      Actions:
        - Name: Deploy
          ActionTypeId:
            Category: Deploy
            Owner: AWS
            Version: 1
            Provider: ECS
          Configuration:
            ClusterName: !Ref Cluster
            ServiceName: !Ref Service
            FileName: images.json
          InputArtifacts:
            - Name: BuildOutput
          RunOrder: 1
```

And the `ecs_template.yml` would look something like this:

```
Parameters:
  Cpu:
    Default: 1024
  Memory:
    Default: 1GB

Resources:
  TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Cpu: !Ref Cpu
          Memory: !Ref Memory
          # ...
```

Comment: How will the service I am deploying onto make reference to the task definition that is being created by this stack?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, can you elaborate? Maybe having the ARN of the task definition in the Outputs of the template and cross-reference it would do?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the only way was to create a new task definition as the deploy pipeline gonna use that one as a base.

Comment: This didn't work for me. After creating the new task definition and rerunning the pipeline, the configuration of the previous task definition was used instead of the new task definition I created.